# Promises vs Reactive vs?

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

so I know Promises and Functional Reactive Programming.

What I want to do is to call an async function and .then(callback) do something, but I do not want to define the callback right away. It reminds me of RxJS Observable, just without all the fancy features..

Maybe someone knows what I am looking for.

Comment: You can store a promise in a variable and add the `.then` callbacks at a later point - does that solve your problem?

Comment: I've never understood why someone asks a question here, gets a comment or an answer asking for clarification and the OP disappears.  They aren't around.  Makes no sense.  Your opportunity for exposure on a question is maximized in the first 20-30 minutes after you post (when your question is newest).  If it's unclear and people ask for clarification and you don't respond, you are just wasting your question entirely and this is what happens - it gets put on hold or closed for other reasons.

Comment: @jfriend00: (New) people just don't expect that. In Forums, newsgroups et cetera you simpy check out responses the other day, and then answer with clarifications. SO is too fast :-)

Comment: @Bergi - yeah, SO is different.  That why we need to educate new folks that their best opportunity for attention to their question is in the first 30 minutes after posting and if their question isn't clear in that time, they will at best just miss most of the people who could/would help or at worst, their question will be closed or put on hold as this one was.  Thus why I added this comment (I'm hoping the OP reads it and gets an understanding for this).  For me personally, I don't look at ANY older questions unless they have some sort of unique tag on them that I just happen to be looking at.

Comment: @jfriend00 make a meta post, you can count on my vote

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - what would you suggest I ask in a meta post?

Comment: @jfriend00 for better feedback for users suggesting they should stick around for at least X minutes after posting, even maybe showing a timer since they've asked their question and emphasizing how important it is to stick around

Comment: @jfreidn00: it's just like Bergi said. Nevertheless I am sorry, I totally get your point.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum- I posted in meta about the newbie poster not being around after posting: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268815/how-can-we-make-sure-that-new-posters-know-that-they-should-remain-available-ove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `.then()` handler that will look at a variable that you can fill in anytime before the `.then()` handler actually fires.

```
var pcallback;
mypromise.then(function() {
    if (pcallback) {
        return pcallback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Then, anytime before the `.then()` handler fires, you can fill in the `pcallback` variable.

---

Or, you can save a reference to the promise and then add the `.then()` handler at any time later.  If you add it after the promise has been resolved, then adding the `.then()` handler will call it immediately (slightly different behavior than the code example above).

Comment: The last point you mentioned is exactly what I needed. I thought I already tested this behaviour, but it seems like I failed at some point. I am sorry again for the unnecessary question!